# How to use protected variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In php we can define variables mainly in three ways:

1. private
2. protected
3. public

In javascript we can define variables like this:

```
function myfunc(){
    var x = 'private'; // private variable
    this.x = 'public'; // public variable
}
```

Now, I want to know how can I maintain **protected** variable in javascript?

---

Is this an answer?

```
function myfunc(){
    var x = { //private variable
        protectedVariable = 'protected'; //protected variable?
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533590/declaring-protected-variable-in-javascript

Comment: private and protected are about the same in js, since there are no classes/subclasses/superclasses

Comment: @dandavis why do you think so? In js we can make sense of use classes/subclasses/superclasses.

Comment: this is as close as i could come, but yuck: http://jsfiddle.net/YPSLT/

Comment: @dandavis post it as an answer.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar: i can't or i would have (duped). it's rough anyway, but you could make the nitty gritty repetitive parts into a callable re-usable routine to give you a sugary way to declare that capability inside the constructor, if you really wanted to use the pattern. personally, i would stick with what's built-in to JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define private scope in JavaScript using closures, but the language doesn't support granular scope identifiers like PHP does.